# How best should I set up ASP.NET (with WCF and DB) solution's server environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

I am architecting a .net web solution which will run on 5 different WCF services and SQL Server databases deployed on the same machine.

I wanted to understand how best I should configure the environment? Do I need development, staging, UAT and live separate servers or should development server be developers' machine or should common databases be stored in the development server? Should staging and UAT environments be same servers?

Is there an article that you recommend which talks about it?

Comment: Depends entirely on budget, project, client, hardware, and a lot of other things. Not sure there is a "right" answer here, except: do NOT put UAT / prod together... what if the bug found in UAT is "causes server to redline", "causes server to blusescreen", or "causes security breach threatening server". Or just "config error causes connect to prod DB"

Comment: That's not something that anyone here can really answer for you. Like Marc said, it really depends on the company and the budget. There really is no *right* answer to this question.

Comment: thanks for your answers.  is there any article that gives a scenerio and talks about different envirnoments that you can recommend please?

Comment: See [Top 4 Reasons Why a Shared Development Database Is Evil](http://blog.benday.com/archive/2011/01/25/23303.aspx)

Comment: I agree with everyone else, it's down to budget however, this can be alleviated by using a virtualisation platform such as VMware to seperate but also consolidate your environments across a reduced amount of physical servers. As always benchmarking and performance should be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your requirements, schedule and budget.

Putting multiple DBs on a single server is workable, provided you have enough RAM and enough disk spindles/throughput (or SSDs). One important key to not promptly running into performance headaches is to make sure the DB log files are different spindles from the DB data files and from each other.

For development, staging and UAT, one strategy is to run three different VMs, hosted on a single physical machine. That allowed quick resets and full isolation from one system to the other.

If you need to do load testing, that environment should generally be separate from the others.